# Find all the $C^1$-solutions of $u_x+2xy^2 u_y = 0.$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

It's a basic exercise in Strauss book to find the solutions of the PDE : $u_x+2xy^2 u_y = 0.$

Using the characteristics method, one finds $u(x,y) = f\left(x^2 + \frac{1}{y}\right)$ where $f$ is arbitrary. However I notice that this solution is not defined if $y=0$ while the original PDE is.

Therefore, how can I obtain all the solutions $u \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2) ?$  (Without any boundary conditions) My idea is to simply say that these solutions are like the previous one with an extra-condition on $f$ : $(x,y) \mapsto f\left(x^2 + \frac{1}{y}\right)$ must be extendible in a $C^1$-way in $(0,0).$ However I doubt that this would allow me to get something very explicit.

Comment: Is it not enough to restrict the initial conditions so that $f$ is smooth and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x) = c$ and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f'(x) = 0$?